# adding elements to the same array being iterated in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I have a JavaScript array of length 3

```
arr = [1, 3, 8];
```

Is there a way to add elements to `arr` while I am iterating over it? I want to insert two values 10 and 20 into the existing `arr`. Can I do it like this? The newly added elements, 10 and 20, must also be looped over in the same for in loop.

```
for(var i in arr) {
  if( i == 0 ) {
   arr[length + 0] = 10;
   arr[length + 1] = 20;
  }
}
```

Or, what is the correct way to add elements to an array while iterating and making sure that the newly added elements will also be looped over?

Comment: Use the other `for` loop `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` and use `arr.push(10); arr.push(20);` instead of `arr[length+0]`

Comment: `for (var ... in ...)` is only meant for objects: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Do the additional elements **need** to be added during iteration? Why can't they be added first?

Comment: @AlanLarimer Most likely he's simplified the code in the question, and the real code is not adding constants like this.

Comment: @Bamar Thanks, I understand that. In knowing the root issue or intent then perhaps an alternative solution can be found.

Comment: You should not use a `for` loop to mutate the entity you are playing with in computer science. You best never do it but if you really need to... a) prepare your array in advance and then iterate by a `for` loop, b) modify it in a `while` loop c) modify it through recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and check the `length` while iterating the array.

With [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), iteration of new elements is not granted.

> Properties added to the object over which iteration is occurring may either be visited or omitted from iteration. In general it is best not to add, modify or remove properties from the object during iteration, other than the property currently being visited.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 8],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
    if (i === 0) {
        array.push(10, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the additional elements **need** to be added during iteration? Why can't they be added first?

Comment: @AlanLarimer, the op stated it. if added before iteration, it would not need some change, beside of the critical use of `for ... in`.

Comment: Sorry. Accidentally commented on your answer, meant to comment on OP.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't ever need to do this, there's probably a better method. But, if you absolutely have to, use a while loop instead:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
  if( i == 0 ) {
    arr.push(10, 20);
  }
  console.log(arr[i]); // 1, 2, 3, 10, 20
  i++;
}
```

Comment: The more idiomatic way to add to an array is `arr.push(10)`.

Comment: yep, was in a rush so I had just copied his code. Will edit